# Premium-rate telephone numbers that produce a familiar sounding melody when typed in

Tags: phone

Some people got really creative and used the dialer to play melodies. Popular is the song *Happy Birthday*, which is showed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2OSskuaZFY).

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiyWINIU2CM) is another awesome example.

Companies often want a number to have "a word in them", so called [phonewords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword).

My question, are there companies that have chosen a phone number based on how it sounds when you type it in, to play a familiar sounding melody?

Comment: Touch-tone phones are hardly used by the majority of people these days, so I doubt any company would go through the trouble, really. This reminds me of that hacker who, a judge said, was a danger to the world, because he was so good, he could start a nuclear war by whistling into a public telephone.